# long datatype loses value on ajax response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my frontend application (ASP.NET MVC 5), I'm calling an API (ASP.NET Web Api 2) through AJAX. The Api's is responding with JSON object:

```
{ Id = 131065867979479430 }
```

However, when frontend receives the response, it becomes:

```
{ Id = 131065867979479420 }
```

There is a difference of 10. 
I looked at Fiddler and the JSON value is displaying as:

```
Id=1.3106586797947942E+17
```

Anyone who has experienced this kind of behavior? How did you fix it?